# Making table fill the page vertically

Tags: tables, spacing

I have several tables in my document that are *just* a bit too small to fill the entire page, vertically.

I'd like to stretch the table, either by adding empty lines at the bottom, or by stretching the lineskip, so that the table fills the text area.

How would I go about this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook} % because that is what I use

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B}\\
\hline
\lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2] \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I want the red-marked whitespace to disappear, i.e. the table borders to match the textarea borders.

[image]

Note that this is contrived. In the real document, this is about `sidewaystable` - making the non-textarea height much more disruptive for the overall layout, and removing the option of simply having surrounding text take up the whitespace.

Comment: Take a look at package `tabularht`. It deals with the spacing between rows, however the line spacing inside a table cell is not affected.

Comment: which is better of course depends whether you have enough table rows to add the space between, in an example like the MWE where ether  only two rows adding space within the row makes more sense, You could do both of course. I don't understand the "package" comment you can stick the definition in `ugg.sty` and use `\usepackage{ugg}` as an alternative to putting it in the preamble, it is the same thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm a programmer. It's the decision between using an include from "the standard library", or adding copypasted code to my project. No offense intended, it's a matter of personal preference. (Besides, Heiko's package doesn't work properly in my real document, so "better" is still open to discussion. ;-) )

Comment: yes but you're using tabularx and that's just some answer I posted to comp.text.tex one day so the difference doesn't seem so great to me:-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I had some trouble with `tabularht`. Apparently the vertical space of the caption is not taken into account; i.e., a `tabularht` with a height of `\textheight` and a caption extends below the text area by exactly the height of the caption.

Comment: @DevSolar Either put the `\caption` inside the tabular or put the `\caption` inside a box, and reduce the tabular by the height of the caption box.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: See my answer below. Would it be feasible to *redefine* the standard `\caption` in the scope of a `tabularht` so that it sets `\TabularhtHeight` (or a similar value under some other name)? I could imagine setting a table to page-height is something many users of `tabularht` might want. (Just guessing, though.)

Comment: @DevSolar I have added an answer with two other possibilities to set a caption inside the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution, where the caption is put inside the tables (example tables taken from the answers of David Carlisle and DevSolar):

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}   

\newdimen\orgtextwidth
\setlength{\orgtextwidth}{\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularhtx}{\textheight}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\noalign{%
  \caption{This is an example}%
}
\hline
\interrowfill
\textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B}\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\interrowfill
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2]\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\end{tabularhtx}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabularht}{\textheight}{|l|}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \hss
    \centerline{%
      \parbox{\linewidth}{%
       \caption{This is an example}%
      }%
    }%  
    \hss
  }%
}\\ 
\hline
\interrowfill
\textbf{Col.}\\
\interrowfill  
\hline
\interrowfill
abc\\
\interrowfill
def\\
\interrowfill
ghi\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\end{tabularht}
\end{table*}   

\clearpage

\begin{sidewaystable*}
\begin{tabularhtx}{\orgtextwidth}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\noalign{\captionabove{This is an example}}
\hline
\interrowfill
\textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B}\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\interrowfill
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2]\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\end{tabularhtx}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

- The horizontal position inside `\noalign` is the left border of the tabular. Because the width of the tabular is not known here, a proper centering is only possible, if the table spans the full width.
- KOMA-Script option `captions=tableheadings` added to get the correct spacing for the table captions.
- Inside `sidewaystable*` `\captionabove` is used, because KOMA-Script fails to see that this is also a table.

Comment: Much superior (due to less macro magic). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

or the exact opposite of the comment I see @Heiko just made, this affects cells but not table rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook} % because that is what I use

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\def\ugg#1{{%
\sbox{0}{\tx}
\dimen0\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0
\sbox{0}{\advance\normalbaselineskip1pt \tx}
\count@\strip@pt\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0 - \dimen0 \relax\relax
\dimen@\dimexpr\textheight-\ht0-\dp0\relax
\divide\dimen@ \count@
\advance\normalbaselineskip\dimen@ \tx
}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\def\tx{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B}\\
\hline
\lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2] \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}}

\begin{table*}
\ugg{\tx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heiko's comment on [`tabularht`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularht) set me on the right path, and egreg helped me with figuring out [how to take caption height into account](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83087). This is the complete solution. (Perhaps something to consider for includion in `tabularht`?)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}

% These are the packages required by the solution
\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}
\usepackage{calc}

% The sidewaystable environment screws up \textwidth,
% so we have to store its value beforehand.
\newlength{\SidewaysTextHeight}
\setlength{\SidewaysTextHeight}{\textwidth}

% Full-page height minus the vertical size of the caption
\newlength{\TabularhtHeight}

\makeatletter
% \captionht - typeset a caption and simultaneously set \TabularhtHeight
\newcommand{\captionht}[2][]{%
    \stepcounter{table}%
    \setbox\z@=\vbox{\@makecaption\fnum@table{#2}}%
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
    \setlength{\TabularhtHeight}{\textheight-\ht\z@-\lineskip}%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \caption{#2}%
    \else
        \caption[#1]{#2}%
    \fi
}

% \captionwd - as \captionht, but for sidewaystable
\newcommand{\captionwd}[2][]{%
    \stepcounter{table}%
    \setbox\z@=\vbox{\@makecaption\fnum@table{#2}}%
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
    \setlength{\TabularhtHeight}{\SidewaysTextHeight-\ht\z@-\lineskip}%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \caption{#2}%
    \else
        \caption[#1]{#2}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\captionht{Caption} % \captionht for table
\begin{tabularhtx}{\TabularhtHeight}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\interrowfill
\textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B}\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\interrowfill
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2]\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\end{tabularhtx}
\end{table*}

\clearpage

\begin{sidewaystable*}
\captionwd{Caption} % \captionwd for sidewaystable
\begin{tabularhtx}{\TabularhtHeight}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\interrowfill
\textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B}\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\interrowfill
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2]\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\end{tabularhtx}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

You might note that the `sidewaystable` does *not* fit the textarea exactly. I'd welcome any hints as to why that is the case.

**Edit:** Contacted the `rotating` maintainer about the layout issue. Will update here if I recieve feedback.

Comment: I have analyzed the `rotating` bug with the horizontal displacement. The package wrongly assumes that `minipage` with `c` puts the middle line to the base line, but `minipage` uses `\vcenter` here and that means the middle line is put on the math axis. I have made a bug report and suggested a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code trying to achieve tabularx fill the page vertically.
Comments? In which circumstances this may fail?
If the space to fill is less than one line the final \hline will not be drawn!

I did put a \framebox to explicitly see the filled space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newlength{\Start}
\newlength{\End}
\newlength{\Diff}
\newbox{\ParBox}
\geometry{paperheight=300pt,vmargin={0pt,0cm},hmargin{0cm,0cm},footskip=0pt,headsep=0pt,headheight=0pt}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\Start}{\zposy{start}sp}%
\setlength{\End}{\zposy{end}sp}%
\setlength{\Diff}{\Start-\End}
\savebox{\ParBox}{\parbox[t][\Diff]{2cm}{\mbox{}}}%
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{|lXl|}\hline
. & start \the\Start{} - end \the\End & . \\
. & filled space \the\dp\ParBox & . \\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
.&.&.\\
& \framebox{\usebox{\ParBox}} &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%

\vskip-\Start
\vskip-\End
\zsaveposy{start}%
\vfill\zsaveposy{end}%
\end{document}
```