# How to get vertical size of table captions?

Tags: spacing, captions, calculations

I found that the `tabularht` package, which allows to give a fixed vertical size for a tabular, does not take into account the vertical space taken up by a table's caption.

It stands to reason, the caption not actually being part of the tabular but the surrounding table.

However, this effectively keeps me from specifying `\textheight` as the size of the `tabularht`.

Now I would like to, as a workaround, substract the height of the caption from `\textheight`. However, I couldn't figure out how to get that particular measure (font height plus spacing above plus spacing below)?

```
\documentclass{scrbook} % because that is what I use

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularht}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newlength{\CaptionHeight}
\settoheight{...}          % this is where I am stuck
\newlength(\TabularhtHeight}
\setlength{\TabularhtHeight}{\textheight - \CaptionHeight}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Test}
\begin{tabularhtx}{\TabularhtHeight}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B}\\
\hline
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2] \\
\interrowfill
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2] \\
\hline
\end{tabularhtx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the sake of both the community and yourself, please provide a working minimal example that members can start with.

Comment: *sigh*... you're a bit OCD about this MWE stuff, you know? The point being, I *don't* know how to get the value, i.e. the example does not and can not "work".

Comment: *"While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not."*

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, but this is about getting a friggin' *length*. Either you know the magic statement that gives the height of a caption, or you don't. I simply don't see where having a tabular exceeding or not exceeding a page height has anything to do with "how to get vertical size of table captions", it's just a bit of fluff to explain *why* I would want that particular value. Anyway, I added the example.

Comment: Well, if there isn't a magic statement, then someone might have taken the time to code something for you in a standard document class with a standard tabular environment.  In addition to having to input a dummy table, the solution then might not have worked with `scrbook` or with `tabularx` and then they would have done all the work for nothing. _That's_ why it's important to give the MWE.

Comment: @ScottH.: I'd rather get the solution that doesn't work with scrbook or tabularx than none at all, because my question is *how to get vertical size of table captions*. I might be able to make do with a 80-20 solution, extend on some partial solution, etc.. Others might later come across this question who have something completely different in mind than working with tabularht. I understand the general need for MWEs, I really do, but sometimes you overdo it here.

Comment: @DevSolar That is a good MWE example. Of course the height of the caption depends on the caption itself, so the computation must be made locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the length locally, because the height of the caption depends on the caption text. Here's a way: we typeset the caption and measure it. The counter must be stepped up and down because the label width can influence the typesetting on one or more lines.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularht}
\usepackage{tabularx,calc}

\newlength{\TabularhtHeight}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\captionht}[2][]{%
  \stepcounter{table}%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{\@makecaption\fnum@table{#2}}%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \setlength{\TabularhtHeight}{\textheight-\ht\z@-\lineskip}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \caption{#2}%
  \else
    \caption[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table*}
\captionht{Test}
\begin{tabularhtx}{\TabularhtHeight}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B}\\
\hline
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2] \\
\interrowfill
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2] \\
\hline
\end{tabularhtx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm... as long as the table is in "normal" orientation. +1 and "correct answer" for that. However, it breaks if you try this in a `sidewaystable` - even if `\textheight` is replaced with `\textwidth` in the macro. The table ends up being *much* too high for the page width. Any idea why?

Comment: @DevSolar I should add that there are some limitations in that code: it's specific for `table` and the caption *must* go before the table. Can you add an example with `sidewaystable`?

Comment: Found the problem with `sidewaystable`: Apparently, the `sidewaystable` environment changes `\textwidth` to some larger value (`\textheight` perhaps?). The reverse is not true - `\textheight` is *not* set to `\textwidth`. So, for the above to work with `sidewaystable`, you have to 1) take the value of `\textwidth` *beforehand*, and 2) write a second version of `\captionht` (I chose `\captionwd`) that uses that pre-taken value instead of `\textheight` for its calculations. Another funny thing is that forgetting to include the `calc` package makes this fail, *silently*.