# Insert image as one third of the page

Tags: graphics

I want to make a macro to insert image in page. 
There are following restrictions:

1. Insert image with caption.
2. Keep aspect ratio of image.
3. Maximize image size.
4. Center image vertically or horizontaly (depending on the size of image, the macro should be universal).
5. Size of resulting object with image and caption must be equal to 1/3 of page height and consume all width.
6. If I put this macro 3 times with absolutely any images and captions, this images must be on the single page, consuming all its size.

Now I'm ended up with the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\oneimage}[2]{
\begin{figure}
\fbox{%
\parbox[b][0.3\textheight][t]{\textwidth}{%
\fbox{\parbox[b][0.26\textheight][c]{\textwidth}{%
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.26\textheight,keepaspectratio]{img/#1}%
}}%
\par%
\fbox{\parbox[b][0.04\textheight][t]{\textwidth}{%
\caption{#2}%
\label{fig:#1}%
}}%
}%
}
\end{figure}
}
```

As you can see, the solution is not perfect, I left about 4 rows for caption, because it is not clear how to force it to consume only necessary amount of rows, and give `1/3 page height - height of caption` to the image. Now the rule "maximize image size" is not implemented honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your macro robust, you need to calculate both the width and the height of your `\parbox`es. The following solution requires the `calc` package.

### Box widths

Each `\fbox` has an inner padding of `\fboxsep+\fboxrule` on each side. Therefore, your inner `\parbox`es should have a width of `\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule`. Furthermore, the actual image loaded with `\includegraphics` should have a width of `\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule`

### Box heights

Here it gets a bit more complicated. For the caption box, you need to account for multi-line captions. You can measure the height of the caption using `\heightof{\parbox[b][][t]{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\@makecaption\fnum@figure{#2}}}` and then add the padding `2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule`. Note that, as done in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83238/150114), I increment and decrement the figure counter to make sure that the right number is used in the "dummy" caption that I measure. This leads to:

```
\stepcounter{figure}
\setlength{\capboxheight}{2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule+\heightof{\parbox[b][][t]{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\@makecaption\fnum@figure{#2}}}}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```

For the figure box, you subtract the caption box height, the padding and the separation between boxes from the total `0.33\textheight-1.4\baselineskip` (this is approximately the  maximum height that still allows three figures to be placed on the same page, and I obtained it through some trial and error):

```
\setlength{\figboxheight}{0.33\textheight-1.4\baselineskip-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-\lineskip-\capboxheight}
```

This produces the following result. The full code and the three test images square.png, flat.png and tall.png (which, as per your code, need to be placed in a directory named `./img/`) are at the end of the post:

[image: threefig]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\capboxheight}
\newlength{\figboxheight}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oneimage}[2]{

\stepcounter{figure}
\setlength{\capboxheight}{2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule+\heightof{\parbox[b][][t]{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\@makecaption\fnum@figure{#2}}}}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}

\setlength{\figboxheight}{0.33\textheight-1.4\baselineskip-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-\lineskip-\capboxheight}

\begin{figure}
\fbox{%
\parbox[b][][t]{\textwidth}{\centering%
\fbox{\parbox[b][\figboxheight][c]{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule,height=\figboxheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,keepaspectratio]{img/#1}%
}}%
\par
\fbox{\parbox[b][\capboxheight][t]{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
    \caption{#2}%
    \label{fig:#1}%
}}%
}%
}
\end{figure}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\oneimage{square.png}{A square.}
\oneimage{flat.png}{A flat rectangle.}
\oneimage{tall.png}{A tall rectangle with a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption that spans 3 lines.}

\end{document}
```

[image: square.png]
[image: flat.png]
[image: tall.png]

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I am looking for! I have a small issue with this approach: I am using **caption** package, so it seems like instead using `\setlength{\capboxheight}...{#2}`, I should use `\setlength{\capboxheight}...{\caption{#2}}`, but it creates an error **Package caption Error: \caption outside float.** I use it, because it gives correct navigation in pdf (jump to image, but not to caption), so I can disable it, but maybe there exist some simple solution?

Comment: Also, I am interesting why it's important to use 0.3\textheight, because when I am using 0.33\textheight, the third image goes on the second page.

Comment: @BhavinChirag There does not seem to be an easy way to use `\caption` inside `\heightof`, because the `\caption` command needs to be inside a `float` (such as a `figure`). That is why I had to add those `\...captionskip` lengths. The reason why `0.33\textheight` does not work is that Latex also adds some spacing between these `\parboxes`, which I unfortunately could not find documentation for. It is probably faster to tweak the `0.33` by trial and error: I got something like `0.33\textheight-1.4\baselineskip` to be very close to the maximum value.

Comment: Maybe there is some problem with parbox **fboxsep** and **fboxrule**? When I do: `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`,`\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.001pt}`, I see some offset from the top of caption, which eliminates, when I also include **caption** package.

Comment: I solved problem with **caption** package, by deleting `+\abovecaptionskip` from `\capboxheight`

Comment: `\heightof` is not considering prefix `Figure 2: `, so there maybe case when height equals only single line, but caption actually consumes two

Comment: @BhavinChirag I fixed the problem with the prefix by using `\@makecaption`. See updated answer.

Comment: With package **caption**, when I substract `\abovecaptionskip` from `\capboxheight`, it works perfectly. It also works when I put two images on single page by replacing 0.33 by 0.5. Thank you!