# Making longtable every last row vfill to the textheight

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable

I found [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82948/making-table-fill-the-page-vertically) and I hope a `longtable`'s last row of every page with a `\vfill` to stretch to the `\texthieght`, so that every page's table is same height.

How would I go about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{6.6cm}|p{6.6cm}|p{2em}|}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering{\Large  caption}}\\\hline
\centering{col A}&\centering{col B}&C\\\hline
\endhead

\lipsum[7]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[5]&&\\[10cm]\hline % i want auto calc and vfill fit the height and remove ``[10cm]''
\lipsum[3]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[1]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[7]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[7]&&\\\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.